# Instagram search box returning empty values using selenium web scraping?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, search-box

So as the title says, whenever I request a user ID that's actually available in instagram accounts and normally would give a result, selenium returns an error page for the exact same ID. What's wrong?
Here is a screenshot and the code I wrote.

```
searchbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Rechercher']")))
searchbox.clear()
searchbox.send_keys("adidas")
searchbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

[Screenshot of the search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NRoP.png)

Comment: I hit enter for the same values and also got nothing.

Comment: Yea, weird! There is a youtube video I found that made same steps & yet got the results by adding a ' # ' before writing the user name in search box. That gave him the wanted results, but this trick doesn't work in my case. Does it work in yours? @ArundeepChohan